# Finding roots in 2-adic numbers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I would like to use Hensel's Lemma to lift the solution to the following equation: $$f(x,y,z)=5x^2+7y^2-13z^2$$ in $Q_2$. The way I tried to approcah this problem is to find such $x_0,y_0,z$ so that $x_0, y_0$ are fixed and  $f(z)\equiv 0\pmod p$ and $f'(z)\not\equiv 0\pmod p$ and then apply Hensel's Lemma. But I was not able to find any such $x_0,y_0,z$.

Thank you!

Comment: I think you need to use the generalised Hensel's lemma, as the derivatives are $10x,14y,-26z$.

Comment: You can find the stronger form of Hensel's Lemma on p. 5 of [these notes](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/gradnumthy/hensel.pdf).

Comment: Thank you! Would you suggest using the stronger version of Hensel's Lemma for other cases as well?